# Diferencia entre loop while y foreach

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo dos códigos para listar una consulta, la conexión es con PDO.

```
$BD = new ConexionDB();
$sql = "SELECT cod, nom from tabla";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$valor = 0;
foreach($sth as $fila) {
    $valor++;
    echo $valor." ";
    echo $fila['cod'];
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Y este otro:

```
$BD = new ConexionDB();
$sql = "SELECT cod, nom from tabla";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$valor = 0;
while ($fila = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $valor++;
    echo $valor." ";
    echo $fila['cod'];
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Ambos códigos funcionan, pero cuál es la manera óptima de hacerlo?
Si quiero hacer un UPDATE a la tabla con un valor incremental colocando este código dentro del bucle en cada caso:

```
$sql= "UPDATE tabla SET orden = ".$valor." WHERE cod = ".$fila['cod'];
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

Funciona con el foreach pero no funciona dentro del while, mostrando este error:

> **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in line** (donde está el while)

Comment: Amigo soy de **.NET**, generalmente en los trabajos con **Base de Datos** es mejor usaur `foreach`, pues no carga toda la información en **RAM**

Comment: El error seguramente es porque esta pisando la variable `$sth` dentro del `while`, intenta usar otro nombre. Lo que me llama la atención es que dice que funciona en el `foreach`... a lo mejor no da error pero no debería funcionar.

Comment: Ambos casos como están planteados funcionan para mostrar los registros  de la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El foreach itera, es decir se convierte en cada elemento de la colección y su duración es igual a la cantidad de elementos que existan en la colección, es la manera más óptima para manejar elementos de listas.

El while es un ciclo que se ejecuta hasta que la condición sea falsa y no necesariamente solo para colecciones :)

Comment: A mi parecer esto no esta correcto, todos los bucles iteran, en bajo nivel todo es lo mismo...

Answer (score 0):

Que yo sepa solo en *MySQL / MySQLi* se podía hacer el `while`, creo que la mejor forma será que selecciones todo y automáticamente lo conviertas a un array.

Algo como esto:

```
$BD = new ConexionDB();
$sql = "SELECT cod, nom from tabla";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$filas = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$valor = 0;
foreach($filas as $fila) {
    $valor++;
    echo $valor." ";
    echo $fila['cod'];
    echo "</br>";
}
```